# Is it possible to make a dependency on a parameterized test in TestNG?

Tags: java, automation, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a test that runs multiple times using a data-provider and it looks something like:

```
@DataProvider(name="data-provider-carmakers")
public Object[][] dataProviderCarMakers() {
    return new Object[][] {
        {CarMaker.Ford},
        {CarMaker.Chevrolet},
        {CarMaker.Renault},
        {CarMaker.Porsche}
    };
}

@Test(  dataProvider = "data-provider-carmakers",
        retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
public void validateCarMakerHasElectricModelsLoaded(CarMaker carMaker) {

    validatecarMakerContainsElectricModelsLoadedInDB(carMaker);
}
```

In another test, I have a dependency to the first:

```
@Test(  dependsOnMethods = { "validateCarMakerHasElectricModelsLoaded" })
public void validateChevroletElectricModelsPowerEfficiency() {

    List<CarModel> electricCarModels = getChevroletCarModels(fuelType.Electric);
    validatePowerEfficiency(electricCarModels);
}
```

(I know the test doesn't make a lot of sense, in reality the code is far more complex that this and data-provider has far more data, but for the sake of clarity I just went with this example).

So I want to run `validateChevroletElectricModelsPowerEfficiency()` only if `validateCarMakerHasElectricModelsLoaded()[CarMaker.Chevrolet]` was successful.

How the code is now, if the first test runs successful for Chevrolet, but fails for Renault, the second test won't run. **Is there a way to make a dependency to just one set of data of a test?**

Comment: you can implement `TestListener` and add some logic in `onTestFailed` for example

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on doing something like that, but then I would need a conditional for every test for every parameter and could look a bit ugly and hard to maintain. I was hoping there was an option I have missed to do the dependency of a specific run of a test, but I think I'm asking for too much. Thanks for the suggestion though, it's not a bad idea.